# How can I get the value of a registry subkey from within a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I found some code to find valid interfaces in Registry keypath `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces`:

```
@echo off

REM DISPLAYS ALL SUBKEYS AND VALUES WITH "{"
REG QUERY HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces /se 
{

pause
```

This code displays All Folders with `{` *(interfaces start always with `{`)*.
And its displays the values to with `{`

I then search for code to find "Interfaces folders" In keyPath `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces`

And call it any name ex:`%ValidInterfaces%`

And do things with it *(sorry i am not english so forgive me)*
so i can do this,  *(%MTU% is 1500)*:

```
%Sys32%reg.exe ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\%ValidInterfaces%" /v MTU /t REG_DWORD /d "%MTU%" /f`
```

Comment: Are you trying to configure the MTU of **all** interfaces to 1500?

Comment: @Compo Yes AM trying to configure  the MTU of all interfaces to 1500